# Login account check

Tags: web-application, vulnerability

Suppose you want to create a new account in any website (let's make it Facebook), how do they check the Gmail ID or any mail ID we entered is a valid mail ID? I observed that some websites are vulnerable to that. How will they verify it?

Comment: they send an email to that account with a link - if you click that link, then they have verified the account - is that what you're thinking about?

Comment: apart from facebook , other websites such as freecharge etc doesn't check with a link for the verification inspite they accept any mail whether it is valid or invalid. so what is the way that they verify  for a valid mail while registering an account . and why are some websites vulnerable.

Comment: So, Facebook is not a good example in your question then?

Comment: What "vulnerability" are you seeing? If the website doesn't care, there is no vulnerability.

Comment: they check the existence of the "@"

Comment: what if they place something before '@' and try to login like (qwerty@gmail.com) even some of the sites are accepting that. my question is that how will they check whether that particular id is valid gmail account or some other account ? do they have access to the database of valid accounts list?

Comment: All the websites I know either they accept anything in the form *@*.xxx or they use a link to validate the email. I never heard of a database or something similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check for the existence an e-mail address, the server can ping that e-mail address against a corresponding SMTP server to validate it.  There are a few steps involved.  Assuming that the user submitted (for example) a gmail address, and assuming that it is your Web application that is doing the validation, you would do the following:

**Step 1:**  Send an nslookup command:

```
nslookup  –type=mx gmail.com
```

This nslookup command will query name servers for that domain. Since we have specified the type as MX, our command will extract and list the MX records of the email domain. Replace gmail.com with the domain of the email address that you are trying to verify.

```
gmail.com MX preference=30, exchanger = alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
gmail.com MX preference=20, exchanger = alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
gmail.com MX preference=5,  exchanger = gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
gmail.com MX preference=10, exchanger = alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
gmail.com MX preference=40, exchanger = alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
```

**Step 2:**  As you may have noticed in the nslookup output, it is not uncommon to have multiple MX records for a domain. Pick any one of the servers listed in the MX records, maybe the one with the lowest preference level number (in our example, gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com), and "pretend" to send a test message to that server from your Web application:

Connect to the mail server via telnet:

```
telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
```

Say hello to the other server:

```
HELO
```

Identify yourself with some fictitious email address:

```
mail from:<your.validation.email@yourdomain.com>
```

Specify the user's e-mail address that you are trying to verify:

```
rcpt to:<my.user@gmail.com>
```

**Step 3:**  Check the response to determine the validity of the e-mail address.  The response for the 'rcpt to' command will give you an idea whether the user's e-mail address is valid or not. If the address exists, the response will be:

```
OK
```

Otherwise, the response will be a 550 error, such as:

```
my.user@gmail.com - The email account that you tried to reach does not exist.
```

...or this:

```
my.user@gmail.com - The email account that you tried to reach is disabled.
```

Answer above was adapted and borrowed from here:

http://www.labnol.org/software/verify-email-address/18220/

**How to do this in PHP:**

```
// include SMTP Email Validation Class
require_once('smtp_validateEmail.class.php');

// the email to validate
$email = 'user@example.com';
// an optional sender
$sender = 'user@mydomain.com';
// instantiate the class
$SMTP_Validator = new SMTP_validateEmail();
// turn on debugging if you want to view the SMTP transaction
$SMTP_Validator->debug = true;
// do the validation
$results = $SMTP_Validator->validate(array($email), $sender);
// view results
echo $email.' is '.($results[$email] ? 'valid' : 'invalid')."\n";

// send email? 
if ($results[$email]) {
  //mail($email, 'Confirm Email', 'Please reply to this email to confirm', 'From:'.$sender."\r\n"); // send email
} else {
  echo 'The email addresses you entered is not valid';
}
```

Source of PHP example above:

https://code.google.com/p/php-smtp-email-validation/

Comment: Sure, this CAN be done, but is this the way it IS done?

Comment: No, this is rarely the way it is done. Normally, if you are going to do this check, you also want to check that the person using that email is the owner, iin which case, you would normally send a confirmation email tot he address with a link. The user must confirm using that link before the account is activated

Answer (score 2):

There are two main ways to check an email address: check validity and check existence.

Checking validity is accomplished by verifying if the email address follows the right syntax. There's a set of rules for validity that every email must follow. They are stated on the [RFC 3696](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3696). There's a *["simple" regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)* that can validate an email:

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b.
```

This is a simple and fast, can be done offline, but does not check if the email is real and the user providing the email is the real owner of it.

On the other hand, checking email existence generally is done by sending a link fot the email provided, or sending a email with a special content and requiring the user to reply that email.

This takes more resources, because it's needed to track the email used and the token created to it, and sending or receiving email. On the other hand, it confirms that the email is valid, exists, and the user claiming its possession is the real owner of it.

But I don't think that failing to validate an email address is a vulnerability. It could be an oversight, but hardly a vulnerability.